# How to convert 'dmesg' time format to 'real' time format

Tags: ubuntu, time, dmesg

I have (for example) this log entry in `dmesg` output:

```
[600711.395348] do_trap: 6 callbacks suppressed
```

Is there a possibility to convert this 'dmesg' time to 'real' time to know, when this event happend?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27503386/94687

Comment: Related, with usage for `dmesg -T`: https://serverfault.com/q/576139/527559

Answer (score 89, accepted):

It looks as if it was implemented recently for Quantal (12.10) : see http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/17829/ .

Basically, `dmesg` is reported to have a new switch `-T, --ctime`.

---

*Edit.* As another extension on Ignacio's answer, [here](http://linuxaria.com/article/how-to-make-dmesg-timestamp-human-readable?lang=en) are some scripts to enhance dmesg output on older systems.

( Note: for the python version of the code shown there, one will want to replace `&lt;` and `&gt;` back to `<>` to make it usable again. )

---

Finally, for a single value like `600711.395348` one could do

```
ut=`cut -d' ' -f1 </proc/uptime` 
ts=`date +%s` 
date -d"70-1-1 + $ts sec - $ut sec + $(date +%:::z) hour + 600711.395348 sec" +"%F %T"
```

and get the event date and time in the local time zone.

( Please note that due to round-off errors the last second digit probably won't be accurate. ) .

*Edit(2)*: Please note that -- as per Womble's comment below, -- this will only work if the machine was not hibernated etc. ( In that case, one shall better look at `syslog` configs at `/etc/*syslog*` and check the appropriate files. See also: [dmesg vs /var/messages](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35851/whats-the-difference-of-dmesg-output-and-var-log-messages) . )

Comment: And, as an added bonus, if the machine's ever been suspended, you're completely doomed, because the time spent asleep isn't accounted for.

Comment: Womble's comment is super imporant! It will show the wrong time if using a laptop that hibernates or is set in standby. You should use the /var/log/kern.log file to see the actual file.

Comment: One-liner: `date -d"1970-01-01 + $(date +%s) sec - $(cut -d' ' -f1 </proc/uptime) sec + 600711.395348 sec" +"%F %T.%N %Z"`

Comment: Note: I can no longer edit my comment, but instead of `%Z`, it should be `UTC`, since `date +%s` returns seconds since UTC. It would then have to be converted to the local time zone.

Comment: @kgibm : I agree with (2) ; as for (1), it is not that I have anything against one-liners -- but I don't actually see a point for it here: code above is intentionally split in three lines for readability ( I need people to _understand_ how it works, not make it as compact as possible ; for that, I shall better build it up sequentially ) and size ( I would love to have longer variable names, but that makes line 3 look nightmare-ish ); on the other hand, you probably won't type in the whole long line in a terminal, but rather put it in a file and make executable -- so no big win here either.

Comment: @ジョージ I agree with you - your answer teaches better. I was just putting the command in instructions to a customer and thought some people might like a more compact form, but it's definitely for the more advanced users.

Comment: @kgibm : I agree as well - I can perfectly understand why one may want to use this form in an e-mail.

Comment: To add to @womble and oligofren great comments, a good practice can be running "journalctl -k" to see the correct time. For ones who are willing to match a specific phrase, "journalctl -k phrase" can be used. (replace "phrase" with the phrase you're searching for)
Credit to 16851556 who answer this here: [How do I convert dmesg timestamp to custom date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2504130/16851556)

Answer (score 20):

To extend on Ignacio's answer, the entries contained in `dmesg` are typically also logged elsewhere on the system, via syslog, which will give you a "real" timestamp.  Unless Ubuntu have changed the Debian-set default, the log entries should be in `/var/log/kern.log`.

Comment: On Cent OS 5 and 6, the log entry is in /var/log/messages.

Answer (score 11):

The time given in dmesg is in seconds since kernel startup. So, just add that many seconds to when the kernel started running (hint: uptime).

Comment: That will only work if you are using a system that never goes into standby. Otherwise you need to use the logs.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is now old but dmesg now has a built in -e or --reatime option to display the time in the local time.

```
root@bbs:/var/log# dmesg|tail -1
[50755952.379177] Out of memory in UB 1593: OOM killed process 3183 (sbbs) score 0 vm:747204kB, rss:242764kB, swap:88224kB

root@bbs:/var/log# dmesg -e|tail -1
[Feb20 17:10] Out of memory in UB 1593: OOM killed process 3183 (sbbs) score 0 vm:747204kB, rss:242764kB, swap:88224kB
```

Comment: This does not work on Ubuntu 18.04. Not sure about others. However `dmesg -T` does work. See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890789/how-do-i-convert-dmesg-timestamp-to-custom-date-format

Answer (score 2):

On busybox, the 3 liner above didn't work, so here is my way to calculate it one off (replace `1628880.0` with your `dmesg` timestamp):

```
perl -e '@a=split(`/proc/uptime`);print scalar(localtime(time()+$a[0] - 1628880.0)."\n");'
```

Answer (score 2):

`dmesg | perl -pe 'use Unix::Uptime; s/^\[(.*)\]/localtime(time()-Unix::Uptime->uptime()+$1)/e'`

Answer (score 0):

Also in need of this for MacOS.

Ventura's dmesg has only 2 parameters :

`dmesg [-M core] [-N system]`

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/543577)